# routing $.post to controller's method

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-routing

New to laravel, working on a premade project was replicatinga a functionality to another section but now I'm stuck with a:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (17:26:57:137 | error, network)   at http://localhost/testimonials/sort
```

The URL of where the action is made:
http://localhost/*****/public/index.php/admin/testimonials

I have this piece of javascript that gets called by an event:

```
sortTestimonials: function () {
        $("#sortable_1, #sortable_2").sortable({connectWith: ".connectedSortable", stop: function () {
                var t = [];
                t = $(".connectedSortable").sortable("toArray"), 
                $.post("/testimonials/sort", {list: t})
            }})
    },
```

That $.post(..) supposedly goes to my routes.php where I have the routes of the controller/section

```
# Testimonials Routes
    Route::resource('testimonials', 'AdminTestimonialsController', ['except' => ['show', 'destroy']]);
    Route::post('testimonials/toggleVisibility', 'AdminTestimonialsController@toggleVisibility');
    Route::post('testimonials/delete', 'AdminTestimonialsController@delete');
    Route::post('testimonials/sort', 'AdminTestimonialsController@sort');
        //this last one being the one it's supposed to grab
```

And then I have my controller AdminTestimonialsController.php where I can't get to (just showing the method in question obviously)

```
public function sort() {
        $order = Input::get('list');
        if (Request::ajax()) {
                        $result = $this->testimonial->sortArticles($order);
        }
        return Redirect::route('admin.testimonials.index');
    }
```

So what am I doing wrong here or what am I missing for it to work?

Comment: Try defining the `Route::post` routes before `Route::resource`

Comment: @lukasgeiter Makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

As your application doesn't live in the root of your domain you can't just use `/testimonials/sort`. It will make a request to `http://localhost/testimonials/sort` instead of `http://localhost/*****/public/index.php/testimonials/sort`.

You can define a `baseUrl` js variable somewhere in your PHP / Blade template and use that when you make ajax requests.

```
<script>
    var baseUrl = "{{ URL::to('/') }}";
</script>
```

And then *later*:

```
$.post(baseUrl + "/testimonials/sort", {list: t})
```

**Note** that you still need the `/` in front of the URL because the `baseUrl` will be without trailing slash.

Comment: But in that case how does it work for this one for instante? (where I based myself on, on the product section of the site) $.post("products/sort", {list: t})

Comment: You can keep the URLs that are relative to your current one like they are.